# I want to pass variable in different function from same controller - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function chat($id,$team1,$team2){

    $relation=Crelation::where('match_id',$id)->where('first_team_id',$team1)->where('second_team_id',$team2)->first();

    if($relation == null){

        $data=[
            'match_id'=>$id,
            'first_team_id'=>$team1,
            'second_team_id'=>$team2
        ];

        $rel=  Crelation::create($data);
       $whatRelation=$rel->id;
        $this->sendMessage($whatRelation);

    }else{

    $whatRelation=$relation->id;
        $this->sendMessage($whatRelation);
    }

    return view('chat',compact('whatRelation'));
}


public function sendMessage(Request $request,$whatRelation)
{

    $id=(int)$whatRelation;

$user = Auth::user();

$message = $user->messages()->create([
    'message' => $request->input('message'),
    'crelation_id'=>$id


]);

broadcast(new MessageSent($user, $message))->toOthers();

return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
}
```

I get this error :

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\ChatsController::sendMessage() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, integer given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ScrimWithMe\app\Http\Controllers\ChatsController.php
>   on line 77 and defined

Comment: `public function sendMessage(Request $request,$whatRelation)` 

you are passing integer for first parameter it should be a request.

Comment: Hmm can you explain little more what i need to change i don't understand...

Comment: your passing single argument only $this->sendMessage($whatRelation);

Comment: I am so confused how to send this $whatRelation to function sendMessage ?

Comment: pass like this $this->sendMessage(Request $request,$whatRelation);

Comment: same error again

Comment: i updated my comment try that

Comment: pass like this $this->sendMessage(Request $request,$whatRelation); and access like this public function sendMessage($request,$whatRelation)

Comment: FatalErrorException in ChatsController.php line 72:
syntax error, unexpected '$request' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 3):

you have two parameters needed for the `sendMessage` function .. but you're just passing one parameter ..

what you can do is add another parameter in your `chat` function chat like

```
public function chat(Request $request, $id,$team1,$team2){
    ....
    $this->sendMessage($request,$whatRelation);
}
```

then add a parameter in said function and that should do it ..

Answer (score 0):

@Demonyowh explain all that why you get this error

I think it's [factory design](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) pattern there are two ways to solve your problem

- If your method not used on any other place then remove first parameter and declare class on next line

  ```
  METHOD(){
    $request = new Request();
    // your code;
  }
  ```
- Declare this class parameter in your __construct method